# libxml2: xpath from xmlNode

Tags: c, xml, libxml2

I've looked through the docs and it seems that you can only execute an xpath search from a `xmlDocPtr` by creating an [xpath context](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xpath.html#xmlXPathNewContext). Is there anyway in **libxml2** to xpath search from a `xmlNodePtr`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you can cast `xmlNodePtr` to `xmlDocPtr` and visa-versa.

Comment: libxml2 requires `xmlXPathNewContext()` to be called with a real top-level `xmlDocPtr` pointer, not a type-casted child `xmlNodePtr` pointer.

Comment: Hmm I'm doing the cast and it seems to be working without any problems. No memory leaks or data corruption. The app this is for has now been downloaded 1000+ times and no complaints about the data run through the xml parser. The xpath code for this app is open source: https://github.com/kgn/KGLib/blob/master/Shared/KGXPath.m

Comment: I stand by my earlier comments.  XPath itself is accessing the `children` list from the specified `xmlDocPtr`, which exists in both `xmlDocPtr` and `xmlNodePtr` at the same offset in memory.  That is the reason why it "works".  But the `xmlDocPtr` is passed around to various API functions that do expect a real `xmlDocPtr`, and the API specifically states that `xmlXPathNewContext()` expects an `xmlDocPtr`, not a type-casted `xmlNodePtr`. You really should respect what the API wants, not what happens to work.

Comment: I took a crack at doing it this way and it seems to be reusing data from the first query for each subsequent query. This image shows my original code and the new code that sets the node, and the resulting data view in my app: http://cl.ly/D7vY Do you see anything glaringly wrong with how I implemented your suggestion that would cause the data to be reused?

Answer (score 1):

Call `xmlXPathNewContext`(), specifying the real top-level `xmlDocPtr` for the document, then set the `xmlXPathContext::node` field to the desired `xmlNodePtr` pointer that is a child of the `xmlDocPtr` document.

Comment: I'm doing casting in my code and it seems to be working fine. Is using xmlXPathNewContext the recommended way of doing this? It doesn't seem to be required. `xmlXPathContextPtr xpContext = xmlXPathNewContext((xmlDocPtr)node);`

Comment: Looking at the libxml2 source code, it expects the `xmlDocPtr` parameter to point to a real `xmlDoc` object.  It is passed around internally as the `xmlDocPtr` parameter of various API calls. `xmlXPathContext` has a separate `node` field that is used for tracking the actual document child `xmlNodePtr` that is being worked on. Just because passing an `xmlNodePtr` pointer as a type-casted `xmlDocPtr` pointer "seems to work" does not make it the right thing to do.